# Translating "proceed to checkout" button woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Can anyone please help me with this?
I dont want "proceed to checkout" on my cart page.

I need to translate that text, it is verry important.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Override the cart template](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/). The text is right there.

Answer (score 3):

I thought it would be a filter, but it turns out that the checkout link is a "pluggable function" instead. Place the following in your theme's functions.php:

```
function woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout() {
        $checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();

        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $checkout_url; ?>" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward"><?php _e( 'Checkout is this way' ); ?></a>
        <?php
    }
```

**However**, the string is translation-ready and so should be translatable either by loading a language .mo/.po pack from Woothemes in the target language or using any translation plugin.